# ¿Como arreglar el movimiento del posicionamiento de botones u otros elementos al iniciar la aplicacion?

Tags: visual-studio, wpf, xaml

Tengo realizada la siguiente parte de la interfaz [image: Diseño establecido]

Pero al momento de iniciar la aplicacion se cambian de posicion y queda lo siguiente

[image: Aplicacion en ejecucion]

la lupa es un icono en **Button**  que esta puesto sobre un TextBox

el codigo de los tres elementos es el siguiente realizado con **Visual Studio** en una ventana **(WPF)**

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbBusqueda" Height="30" Margin="0,10,197,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Ingrese su busqueda" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="230" GotFocus="tbBusqueda_GotFocus"/>
<Button x:Name="btnBuscar" Margin="535,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Click="btnBuscar_Click" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="30">
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbBuscarPor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Buscar por " Margin="210,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBoxItem Visibility="Collapsed">Buscar por</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Nombre" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Apellido paterno" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Puesto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con un trozo tan limitado de XAML es difícil, pero creo que tu problema es que estás definiendo las posiciones mediante el manejo de los márgenes, por ejemplo le dices que el boton esté a 535 pixeles del borde izquierdo y el combobox a 210.

Esa solución no es óptima, lo que yo haría (hay mil soluciones) es colocar -en el área que ocupan los 3 controles- un Grid y dividirlo mediante ColumnDefinitions para así definir los espacios.

```
<Grid Height="30">
    <!-- el ancho tu ves como defines -->        
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="230"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbBuscarPor" Text="Buscar por " IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" Height="30" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
        <!-- IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" para que se muestre el Texto sin agregarlo como item -->
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Nombre" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Apellido paterno" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Puesto" />
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="tbBusqueda" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Ingrese su busqueda"  GotFocus="tbBusqueda_GotFocus" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Buscar por" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Con eso no tienes que definir márgenes innecesarios ni preocuparte de los espacios, solo le dices cuanto mide cada columna dentro del grid y pones los controles en la columna que corresponda y posición dentro de ella.

Un saludo.